# IIS6 can't find site on local network

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, nic

I have a windows 2003 server with dual NICs running IIS6. I can access everything remotely, but the internal network can't seem to find the site regardless of which IP Address I try to go to. There are really several weird things that are happening here, but I'm going to limit this question to what I'm guessing to be the simplest problem (the solution to which I'm hoping solves other things as well):

- From the server itself, I can access the webpage using the primary IP address (i.e. `http://192.168.1.2/index.htm`), but not using the secondary IP address (i.e. `http://10.10.10.2/index.htm`).

Self pinging both IP addresses works, and the "Web site identification" in IIS has the IP address set to "(All Unassigned)"... which I believe should bind both IP addresses to this site.

I apologize if I'm not providing enough details about my setup, but at this point I don't even know what's relevant...

**UPDATE**

I found part of the problem (Thanks @SimonCatlin for pointing me in that direction).  The server wasn't listening on port 80 on the 10.10.10.x subnet.  After I changed that, the server delivers the webpage locally to both `http://192.168.1.2/index.htm` and `http://10.10.10.2/index.htm`).

I used the following commands to listen on port 80 via all NICs

```
> httpcfg delete iplisten -i 192.168.1.2
> httpcfg set iplisten -i 0.0.0.0
> net stop http
> net start http
> iisreset
```

I checked and verified this by running `netstat -oan`, which now returns the following relevant data:

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
```

Here's my current list of things that did't work:

- **FIXED** From the server itself, browsing to `http://10.10.10.2/index.htm`
- **FIXED** From the 10.10.10.x subnet, browsing to `http://10.10.10.2/index.htm`
- From the 10.10.10.x subnet, browsing to `http://[staticIP]/index.htm`
- From the 10.10.10.x subnet, browsing to `http://mydomain.com/index.htm`

If I run a `nslookup mydomain.com` it returns the staticIP, so I'm guessing the last two points are the same problem.

Comment: Are there any other sites on the server?

Comment: It could happens that internally you resolve DNS names to public IP and your firewall (Cisco ASA for example) is not configured to translate public IP in DNS requests to internal IPs. Can you add your DNS name and internal IP on one of your internal desktops to the hosts file and see if it works?

Answer (score 1):

Your information doesn't stack up (that's not a criticism, just an observation!).

Can you clarify...

Remotely (presumably from another routed network, other than your 192. and 10. subnets), you can get to the site on either IPs?

Internally (presumably from a computer on the 192. or 10. subnets, but NOT from the server itself), you can't get to either site?

From the server console itself, you can get to the site, but only via the 192. address?

You are not using domain names, so host name headers aren't coming into play.

Could you confirm, either using Netstat, or something like SysInternal's TCPView that your server is indeed listening on port 80 on both IPs?  From your remote test above, the assertion is that it is bound to both IPs.

The bizarre thing is that, if you can get to the site on both IPs remotely, then it would suggest that IIS6 is serving content via port 80 on both IPs.  Therefore, locally on the server, where local IPs are accessed without any need for routing, you should get the same content.

Can you please also clarify EXACTLY what error you are receiving when it fails?

Finally, try running up SysInternals' Process Monitor on the server.  Set your filter to watch for file access in your website directory (where index.htm lives), plus network activity on port 80.  Perform your tests and see what results you get (hint - once you set up your filters, enable the "drop filtered events" option to save RAM).

Comment: I've updated my question... it appears the server wasn't listening on the 10.x subnet!  Now my question is the slightly modified, "why can't I get to the page from a machine on the 10.x subnet?"